# How to choose a different color for structure text in notes

Tags: beamer, color, typography

Is there a way to typeset `structure` with different colors in the presentation (slides) and in the notes?

My slides use white font on a black background (for the students to see while I talk) and the notes are black text on a white background (suitable for hard printing).

Structure text, as the table of contents and other elements, is typeset equally on both slides and notes. Therefore, they are invisible in one of them, unless I use a medium gray, what does not look not very pretty in neither.

So: is there a way to choose distinct colors?

I know, so far, that

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=someforeground,bg=somebackground}
```

can be used, but it would be nice to have something like

```
\setbeamercolor{note structure}{fg=someotherforeground,bg=someotherbackground}
```

My workaround is to use `\setbeamercolor` whenever needed, but it's not elegant nor practical.

**Note:** I'm really not quite sure I understood the concepts of `structure`, `local structure` etc. So, feel free to point the right direction if appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically apply the altered structure colour to all note pages, you can use the `\AtBeginNote{}` hook:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\AtBeginNote{\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\structure{normal slide}
\note{\structure{note text}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\structure{normal slide}
\note{\structure{note text}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has been my workaround. I thought to redefine `frame` enclosing it in a new environment, but I found that there are too many options and overlays along title and subtitle variants to pass forward.

Comment: @Jander Why workaround? The colour gets applied to all note pages and the normal frames keep their original colour.

Comment: I confess I was in a hurry and misread your answer. It works fine. But for the table of contents, it works only for sections, subsections remain in the "original" color. I guess subsections are not "structure text". Had to add `\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=black}`.

Comment: I know this could be a new question, but it's only curiosity for now: is it a good practice to use `\AtBeginNote` (ou any other `\AtBegin...`) inside a theme. If yes, where should it go: inner, outer?

Comment: @Jander For a theme, I'd probably use `\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}}{}`. I'm undecided, either it should go into the color theme (because it sets a colour) or outer theme (where the note page template is defined)